# I'm getting npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://artifactory.devops."**********"/artifactory/api/npm/npm/npm

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory

I'm trying to install npm within my project folder but I'm getting the error mentioned in the Title, can anyone please help me out here. PS I was told that we're using an artifactory registry instead of a Node registry.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You just showing an error, but didn't tell us what you're actually doing. *I was told that we're using* - then they (who told you) might be able to tell you what exactly to do or what is wrong, Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry for the Rookie mistake, I was told by a colleague that we use Artifactory and the only thing I did wrong might be I ran a command that sets the HTTPS registry to Null (I've no idea if that's the thing that is causing this issue), I'll seek from colleagues as well but before that just exhausting my option here on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Artifactory npm repository is not correctly configured as the npm registry which in turn returns the 'HTTP 400 - Bad Request' error. Have you followed the instructions from the Set Me Up section available for the NPM repositories in Artifactory?

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYGbN_OcKX8) that explains step by step process to Set Up an NPM Repository in Artifactory.
Consider verifying the steps you have followed with the steps described in the following JFrog wiki as well.

- [Setting the default registry](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry#npmRegistry-SettingtheDefaultRegistry)
- [Authenticating the npm client](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry#npmRegistry-AuthenticatingthenpmClient)
- [Resolving npm packages](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry#npmRegistry-ResolvingnpmPackages)

Comment: I've followed all the steps mentioned above but I'm still getting the same bad request error. Intestrigly, none of my colleagues faced this issue and no one changed a thing in the Jfrog.

Comment: I think I've figured out the issue, I accidentally changed HTTPS to HTTP in the registry URL, may I know if you have an idea for how to change it back to HHTPS?

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the root cause. Do you mean the Artifactory's repository URL? The NPM client configurations would be stored in the .npmrc file and, by default, it would be stored in the following location (./.npmrc). The registry URL from HTTP to HTTPs can be modified through this file.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I've changed the protocol of the registry URL from HTTPS to HTTP using an npm command but I'm not sure which one I ran (i.e) If I give a registry with HTTP it gives me a standard error which I can only fix but if I give HTTPS it gves me Bad request so I'm looking to undo that command I ran.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I've setup a virtual repo with npm registry as remote and a local repository. I setup the client using artifactory, I can pull packages but cannot call `npm audit` since it responds with `Failed to fetch audit report for repo npm. status: 400 cause: {"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Invalid package tree, run  npm install  to rebuild your package-lock.json"}` - which I did.